# Can't find a single custom ROM for my tablet?

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I own a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 8.0 (SM-T330) and I cannot find a single custom ROM for it. I'm getting really frustrated.. What can I do??? The device is rooted with a TWRP custom recovery installed and fully functioning.

Comment: I've looked on XDA and can't find anything non-stock for that device. You can't do anything really. You could install XPOSED framework and tweak nearly everything on your stock ROM. Do you need to do anything? Alternatively you could build your own ROM but that's a huge amount of work really, and probably not what you'd want to do.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll try XPOSED framework. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: You can request for a custom ROM to be made at [Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/threads/general-custom-rom-request-suggestion-center.297857/) or [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/custom-roms), if Xposed is not fully functional.

Answer (score -1):

There does seem to be an unofficial version of Cyanogenmod 12 (Android Lollipop 5). Here is the first article I found:

http://www.android.gs/update-samsung-galaxy-tab-4-8-0-to-android-5-1-1-lollipop-with-unofficial-cm-12-1-rom/

Here is the most up to date version:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/development/rom-cyanogenmod-12-1-t3097152